# read_csv import large numbers

Tags: python, pandas

A sample CSV file has contents like

```
Afghanistan,AFG,8013233121.55065,8689883606.07776,8781610175.40574
```

When I import this with

```
GDP = pd.read_csv('world_bank.csv', header=4, usecols=fields)
```

I get the numbers in scientific notation.

```
Afghanistan,AFG,3.992331e+12,4.559041e+12
```

What is the correct converter to use?

Comment: They are the same thing. This won't affect your calculations, only how they are printed in the console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those numbers are floats.  You are just seeing what is displayed.

Consider the following

```
txt = """Afghanistan,AFG,8013233121.55065,8689883606.07776,8781610175.40574"""

GDP = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), header=None, converters={i:np.float128 for i in [2,3,4]})

print(GDP)

             0    1             2             3             4
0  Afghanistan  AFG  8.013233e+09  8.689884e+09  8.781610e+09
```

---

However, a closer look at one cell

```
GDP.iloc[0, 2]

8013233121.5506496
```

---

To `print` with a float format you like you can.  `pd.set_option('display.float_format', '{:0.6f}'.format)` or do it temporarily

```
with pd.option_context('display.float_format', '{:0.6f}'.format):
    print(GDP)

             0    1                 2                 3                 4
0  Afghanistan  AFG 8013233121.550650 8689883606.077761 8781610175.405741
```