# how to remove e scientific notation from mean method of numpy lib in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, mean, pca

I'm new to python and numpy library.I'm doing PCA on my custom dataset.
I calculate the mean of each row of my dataframe from pandas but I get below result as mean array:

```
[   7.433148e+46
    7.433148e+47
    7.433148e+47
    7.433148e+46
    7.433148e+46
    7.433148e+46
    7.433148e+46
    7.433148e+45
    7.433148e+47]
```

And my code is :

```
   np.set_printoptions(precision=6)
   np.set_printoptions(suppress=False)
   df['mean']=df.mean(axis=1)
   mean_vector = np.array(df.iloc[:,15],dtype=np.float64)

  print('Mean Vector:\n', mean_vector)
```

what's the meaning of this numbers?
and how should I remove e from the number?

Any help really appreciate,
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `7.433148e+47` is `7.433148* (10^47)`, is this what you mean? What if you set `np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)`?

Comment: no ,I know the value . I use np.set_printoptions(suppress=True) to remove e from the numbers as they say in the numpy documents.https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html 
 but it didn't work.

Comment: Well, you might want to look at this question and its answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9777783/suppress-scientific-notation-in-numpy-when-creating-array-from-nested-list

Comment: thanks ,I've checked it before and then used np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)

Comment: See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41645474/2336654)

Comment: thank you alot! it worked! @piRSquared

Comment: I'm reopening this, because I don't think the problem is simply a formatting one.  Something is fishy about a mean of 4e46 size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are these large numbers realistic, and, if so how do you want to display them?

Copy and paste from your question:

```
In [1]: x=np.array([7.433148e+46,7.433148e+47])
```

The default numpy display adds a few decimal pts.

```
In [2]: x
Out[2]: array([  7.43314800e+46,   7.43314800e+47])
```

changing precision doesn't change much

```
In [5]: np.set_printoptions(precision=6)
In [6]: np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)

In [7]: x
Out[7]: array([  7.433148e+46,   7.433148e+47])
```

`suppress` does less.  It supresses small floating point values, not large ones

```
suppress : bool, optional
Whether or not suppress printing of small floating point values using       
scientific notation (default False).
```

The default python display for one of these numbers - also scientific:

```
In [8]: x[0]
Out[8]: 7.4331480000000002e+46
```

With a formatting command we can display it in it's 46+ character glory (or gory detail):

```
In [9]: '%f'%x[0]
Out[9]: '74331480000000001782664341808476383296708673536.000000'
```

If that was a real value I'd prefer to see the scientific notation.

```
In [11]: '%.6g'%x[0]
Out[11]: '7.43315e+46'
```

To illustrate what `suppress` does, print the inverse of this array:

```
In [12]: 1/x
Out[12]: array([ 0.,  0.])

In [13]: np.set_printoptions(suppress=False)

In [14]: 1/x
Out[14]: array([  1.345325e-47,   1.345325e-48])
```

===============

I'm not that familiar with `pandas`, but I wonder if your `mean` calculation makes sense.  What does `pandas` print for `df.iloc[:,15]`?  For the mean to be this large, the original data has to have values of similar size.  How does the source display them?  I wonder if most of your values are smaller, normal values, and your have a few excessively large ones (outliers) that 'distort' the mean.

I think you can simplify the array extraction with `values`:

```
mean_vector = np.array(df.iloc[:,15],dtype=np.float64)
mean_vector = df.iloc[:,15].values
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.No my numbers aren't large ! I don't know how pandas calculated these mean numbers!As I read in their documents df.mean(axis=1), calculate mean for columns and this is one of my columns data :
"83,403,8202,166,151712,189,29,4315,183,1234,2065,2016,4407129,,161096,4570,40636,43132,56822

Comment: There must be some value, may be several, that isn't what you expect - something much larger.  Try `max` over rows or columns.

Comment: thank you so much! exactly i had a lot of repetitive numbers,now I normalized my dataframe using sklearn librarypreprocessing.MinMaxScaler() ,then calculate mean on columns and now I have mean values as below : 0.793219,0.799823,0.540168,0.074821,...,0.039899