# How to save integer array to a file showing numbers as integers

Tags: python-3.x

I am attempting to save an array to a txt file, I used the following function:

`numpy.savetxt('C:/Users/Adminstrator/Desktop/mesh/ELIST2-clean.txt',array2DClean, delimiter='\t')`

The data in file are shown as following:

```
1.300000000000000000e+01    2.710000000000000000e+02    2.360000000000000000e+02    7.200000000000000000e+01    2.350000000000000000e+02
2.400000000000000000e+01    2.760000000000000000e+02    2.060000000000000000e+02    1.310000000000000000e+02    1.300000000000000000e+02
3.200000000000000000e+01    2.580000000000000000e+02    2.820000000000000000e+02    2.570000000000000000e+02    5.000000000000000000e+01
3.600000000000000000e+01    2.800000000000000000e+02    5.100000000000000000e+01    5.000000000000000000e+01    1.030000000000000000e+02
3.900000000000000000e+01    2.800000000000000000e+02    2.250000000000000000e+02    1.120000000000000000e+02    1.110000000000000000e+02
4.300000000000000000e+01    2.810000000000000000e+02    1.630000000000000000e+02    2.200000000000000000e+01    1.640000000000000000e+02
4.900000000000000000e+01    2.850000000000000000e+02    1.150000000000000000e+02    1.600000000000000000e+02    1.610000000000000000e+02
```

How can I format the numbers written to the file as whole integers without xe+y notation?

Comment: When you say whole integers? do you just mean 1, 2, 3 etc?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to remove e scientific notation from mean method of numpy lib in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41654397/how-to-remove-e-scientific-notation-from-mean-method-of-numpy-lib-in-python)

Comment: @torswq, no it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`numpy.savetxt`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) has an argument `fmt` that takes the number format.

> fmt: str or sequence of strs, optional
>
> A single format (%10.5f), a sequence of formats, or a multi-format
> string, e.g. ‘Iteration %d – %10.5f’, in which case delimiter is
> ignored. For complex X, the legal options for fmt are:
>
> a single specifier, fmt=’%.4e’, resulting in numbers formatted like ‘
> (%s+%sj)’ % (fmt, fmt)
>
> a full string specifying every real and imaginary part, e.g. ‘ %.4e
> %+.4ej %.4e %+.4ej %.4e %+.4ej’ for 3 columns
>
> a list of specifiers, one per column - in this case, the real and
> imaginary part must have separate specifiers, e.g. [‘%.3e + %.3ej’,
> ‘(%.15e%+.15ej)’] for 2 columns

Do `numpy.savetxt('C:/Users/Adminstrator/Desktop/mesh/ELIST2-clean.txt',array2DClean, delimiter='\t', fmt='%.0f')` to use a format string that writes floats out in fixed-point notation with zero decimal places.

More info here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language